# How is this sorting code working?

Tags: python

How is this sorting code working? I cannot understand how the values returned by the iterator are being used to sort the list?

```
mylist=["zero","two","one"]
list1=[3,1,2]
it = iter(list1)
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: next(it))
```

Output:

```
['two', 'one', 'zero']
```

Comment: Not an answer, but IMO a more intuitive equivalent is `[x[1] for x in sorted(zip(list1, mylist))]`

Comment: ... or `[mylist[i-1] for i in list1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works like this - the `key=lambda x: next(it)` part is stating: assign an order value of `3`, then `1` then `2` to each of the elements in `mylist`. So `two` comes first, then `one` then `zero`:

```
["zero", "two", "one"] # original list
[  3,      1,     2  ] # assign this order to each element
```

Now, after sorting:

```
[  1,     2,      3  ] # sorted keys
["two", "one", "zero"] # and there you go!
```

Comment: Lopez I did not know that key can be used to assign an order value in this way to a sequence elements. Is there documentation on this ?

Comment: One might conclude then that it relies on an implementation detail, that elements in `mylist` are assigned keys from first to last...?

Comment: @abc `keys=` can be anything you want it to be, it takes as parameter the current element in the original list (which is ignored in this case) and then returns an order value, that will be used for the comparisons that determine how to order the list

Comment: @ThijsvanDien yes, because in this case the original list and the iterator with the ordering criteria are being traversed simultaneously.

Comment: @abc regarding the documentation, here's the relevant [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted). Notice that it states that `"key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default value is None (compare the elements directly)."`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Great comment. Basically key returns the effective value (that is used in lieu of the list element) while sorting the list. And then the list is sorted with original elements intact.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien - That's a very good point. Given that `sorted` operates on iterables, it would be very surprising to see any other order, but nevertheless there is no guarantee in the order the key function will be called with the elements of the iterable...

Answer (score 1):

`next(it)` returns next item of the iterable every time it's called:

```
>>> list1=[3,1,2]
>>> it = iter(list1)
>>> print next(it)
3
>>> print next(it)
1
>>> print next(it)
2
```

`key` is a function that is called on each list element for making comparisons.

`sorted()`: If you don't specify `key` parameter it will compare item values, if you provide `key` - it uses the result of `key` function calls for making comparisons between items of the list.

So, for `"zero"` it is `3`, for `"two"` - `1`, for `"one"` - `2`. Since `1 < 2 < 3`, the result is `["two", "one", "zero"]`.

Comment: Right. But the way sorted is using the return values of key function in this case to assign an order is very interesting. Is there some documentation on this ?

Comment: @abc well, there is a good tutorial [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).